# Does the HDMI output of a Nikon D750 use HDCP?

Tags: nikon, video

I need to capture live video (1280x720-60 fps) from a Nikon D750, with a capture card that does not support HDCP signal. The capture card is equipped with a classic HDMI input, while the Nikon comes with a mini-HDMI output. To capture the video, with the capture card, using the classic HDMI cable, I have to use a mini HDMI-HDMI adapter.

Does the Nikon D750 use HDCP on its outputs (mini-HDMI)? If Nikon does not use HDCP, using the adapter, can it create HDCP?

Comment: When you say HDCP are you referring to the protocol?

Comment: High-bandwidth Digital Content Protection (HDCP)

Answer (score 1):

A mini-HDMI to HDMI adapter will not impact the presence of HDCP on the signal, it merely changes the connector passively.  As to whether your Nikon uses HDCP or not, I'm unsure.  My Canon 5D Mark iii also uses a mini-HDMI output and the first couple cables and adapters I got didn't connect very reliably, so I had signal issues until I found a cable that worked well.

You may be having a similar problem to this or it could be HDCP causing issues.  I'd recommend two things you can try in order to troubleshoot this issue.  First, try connecting a known HDCP signal, such as a bluray player to your capture card and see what happens.  It may simply give no signal or it may give an error.  If it gives an error, then you will know that your camera is simply not connecting (unless you get the same error about HDCP being present).

If this is inconclusive, you could also try connecting the camera to a TV that supports HDCP or connecting another mini-HDMI device to the capture device and see if either of those situations work.

It is possible that Nikon may have actually included HDCP in an anti-consumer move intended to prevent use of DSLRs for high end video production, but this seems like an odd choice for them as they have no product in that market segment.  (HDCP would allow connecting to TVs, but prevent use in recording and most video mixers for event production.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73315/discussion-between-aj-henderson-and-edward).

Answer (score 0):

It uses a Data [Type C mini-pin HDMI connector](http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/d750.htm) and this does indeed [support HDCP](https://www.hdmi.org/manufacturer/hdmialtmodeusbtypec.aspx).

According to [this post](http://www.dvxuser.com/V6/showthread.php?337547-Nikon-D750-and-Marshall-monitor-compatibility) here, the D750 does indeed use HDCP, however, this seems incredibly hard to find much information on and it's not an "official" source.

Comment: so,
if the Nikon D750 uses HDCP, which would be the best solution, to capture the signal correctly to the capture card without HDCP?
On this topic, it is often recommended, a type of splitter that substantially removes HDCP, connected directly to the capture card with HDMI cable not compatible with HDCP.

Comment: Nikon connected to adapter,
adapter connected to the splitter with HDMI cable compatible HDCP,
splitter connected to the capture card with a cable that does not compatible to HDCP.

But what kind of adapter should you use?

In all this, the Nikon is 8 m away from the PC and the capture card,
so the HDMI cable, which runs from the splitter to the capture card, what kind of HDMI should it be?

Comment: "I hope to hell that's not true...because that would be the dumbest thing I've heard of from that company." - Exactly. [Note that HDCP's website does not list Nikon products](https://www.digital-cp.com/hdcp-products?title_1=nikon&title=&field_product_description_value=&field_product_technology_value=All) - which does not prove or refute anything. Then again, [this article in German](https://www.heise.de/newsticker/meldung/Erster-HDMI-Recorder-fuer-4K-und-1080p120-Videos-2180099.html) says that the Shogun "respects HDCP, which Atomos says is to support DSLRs and (semi-)professional camcorders."